# Jessie: can't boot the kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64

Tags: debian, boot, lvm

I have been using Jessie for a few months now, and I had a problem booting my computer a few weeks ago.

I had this error on boot:

```
early console in decompress_kernel

Decompressing Linux... Parsing ELF... done.
Booting the kernel.
Loading, please wait...
fsck from utils-linux 2.25.2
/dev/mapper/fabienm-root: clean, 12578/262144 files, 179719/1048576 blocks
Gave up waiting for /usr device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/fabienm-usr does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
(initramfs)
```

If I select the `3.16-2-amd64` kernel in Grub, that boots "correctly?" and produces this log:

```
early console in decompress_kernel

Decompressing Linux... Parsing ELF... done.
Booting the kernel.
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
Loading, please wait...
[    6.300000] systemd-fsck[173]: /dev/mapper/fabienm-root: clean, 12578/262144 files, 179719/1048576 blocks
[    8.700000] [drm:cpt_set_fifo_inderrun_reporting] «ERROR» uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[    8.700000] [drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] «ERROR» PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[    9.000000] systemd-fsck[432]: /dev/sdb1: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
[   11.200000] systemd-fsck[553]: /dev/mapper/fabienm-var: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
[   11.600000] systemd-fsck[560]: /dev/mapper/fabienm-home: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
[   11.700000] systemd-fsck[564]: /dev/mapper/fabienm-usr: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
[   11.900000] systemd-fsck[578]: /dev/mapper/fabienm-tmp: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
see 'systemctl status virtualbox.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Start or stop the inetd deamon..
[  OK  ] Started LSB: KernelNFS server support.
...
```

Once I booted with this working kernel, I can look at /proc/cmdline:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16-2-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/fabienm-root ro quiet
```

This kernel works well with all Debian packages except for Virtualbox, which requires `3.16.0-4-amd64` kernel to work.

Does someone has a clue how to enable the `3.16.0-4-amd64` kernel to boot on Jessie?

[edit]

On initramfr (kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64) I launched somes commands :

```
(initramfs) grep dm_mod /proc/modules
dm_mod 89373 4 - live 0xFFFFFFFFA023E000
```

And in /dev/mapper I only see fabienm-root partition :

```
(initramfs) ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 0 0 10, 236 Mar 25 12:39 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0       7 Mar 25 12:39 fabienm-root -> ../dm-0
```

Under booted linux (3.16-2-amd64) I have:

```
$ ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 mars  25 13:44 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 mars  25 13:44 fabienm-home -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 mars  25 13:44 fabienm-root -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 mars  25 13:44 fabienm-swap_1 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 mars  25 13:44 fabienm-tmp -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 mars  25 13:44 fabienm-usr -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 mars  25 13:44 fabienm-var -> ../dm-2
```

and :

```
$ grep dm_mod /proc/modules
dm_mod 89373 20 - Live 0xffffffffa021f000
```

Comment: `/dev/mapper/fabienm-root`? Do you have some unusual LVM setup? Also, please consider posting this to the Debian bug tracker; it's impossible to tell for sure from what you've posted here, but it smells a bit like a potential release-critical bug.

Comment: You can boot to that kernel, actually, you can't find root. Please check that dm-mod is loaded into problematic kernel: `# grep dm_mod /proc/modules`. Root device exists: `# ls -l  /dev/mapper/fabienm-usr `

Comment: `lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64 | grep script ` Is there a lvm script inside of it?

Comment: nwildner: your command give me a script with lvm2 name :
`scripts/local-top/lvm2`. I've got exactly the same files scripts tree with 3.16-2-amd64 initrd file.

Comment: Are the `/dev/dm-0` .. `/dev/dm-5` device entries perhaps there, despite not having symlinks from `/dev/mapper/` pointing there?