# Debian jessie volume group not found and can't boot

Tags: debian, boot, chroot, initramfs

I have accidentally deleted my boot partition. OS is Debian Jessie with LUKS LVM. I have created a new partition and successfully reinstalled grub with the chroot method.

Now when I try to boot, my root partition cannot be found.

I get the following error message and then prompts to initramfs.

> Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
>
> Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline )
>
> Check root delay = (did the system wait long enough)
>
> Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
>
> Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
>
> ALERT! /dev/mapper/vg--mypc-root does not exist.
>
> Dropping to shell!
>
> modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep

I found this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192387/jessie-cant-boot-the-kernel-3-16-0-4-amd64). Maybe it is the same problem.

I have done the following things:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 mylvm

lvmscandisk
```

> /dev/mapper/mylvm [     178,33 GiB] LVM physical volume
>
> /dev/sda1         [     243,00 MiB]
>
> /dev/sda5         [     178,33 GiB]

```
vgchange -ay
```

> 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "mypc-vg" now active

```
lvscan
```

> ACTIVE  '/dev/mypc-vg/root' [178,33 GiB] inherit
>
> ACTIVE  '/dev/mypc-vg/swap_1' [9,08 GiB] inherit

```
mount /dev/mypc-vg/root /mnt

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot

mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

chroot /mnt

aptitude reinstall grub2-common grub-pc-bin grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-common

aptitude reinstall linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

I also have reinstalled lvm2 in chroot environment without effect. update-grub and grub-install give no errors but during booting, but it still prompts to initramfs console.

Then I tried to copy all *.deb files from livecd to chroot'ed /tmp folder and run `dpkg -i *deb` to install all packages to the filesystem. This had also no effect. Was found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26886/fixing-unbootable-installation-on-lvm-root-from-desktop-livecd).

Now I don't know what to do next. I think I am going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like volume group is called `mypc-vg`, but your kernel command line references `vg-mypc`. Fix that by editing the boot arguments in GRUB before booting. Then make the change permanent by reconfiguring GRUB from the running system.